# Ember template not reloading after i set cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, ember.js

I have a little problem. 
I have a "use-button" which sets a cookie, telling that this deal is used. The button switch state to disabled.

The problem is that, if you go back and forwards, the button is no longer disabled and you can still use the button. If you refresh the page the button will be disabled.

This is my code:

```js
export default Ember.Controller.extend(MobileHelper, {
  goodie: Ember.computed.alias('model'),
  tracker: Ember.inject.service(),
  used: undefined,
  fieldUsed: function(){
    var pack_id = this.get('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id');
    var cookies;
    if (this.cookie.getCookie('gp_pv') === undefined) {
      return false;
    } else {
      cookies = JSON.parse(this.cookie.getCookie('gp_pv'));
    }
    return cookies[String(pack_id)] === 1;
  }.property('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id'),

  profileComponent: function() {
    return `goodie-${this.get('goodie.type')}-profile`;
  }.property('goodie.type'),
  
  actions: {
    markSwiped: function() {
      var cookies;
      if (confirm("Er du sikker?")){
        if (this.cookie.getCookie('gp_pv') === undefined){
          cookies = {};
        } else {
          cookies = JSON.parse(this.cookie.getCookie('gp_pv'));
        }
        var pack_id = this.get('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id');
        if (cookies[String(pack_id)] !== 1){
          cookies[String(pack_id)] = 1;
        }
        jQuery("#itemUsable").hide();
        jQuery("#itemUsed").show(); 

        this.get('tracker').trackGoodieExternalLinkClick(this.get('goodie'));       

        this.cookie.setCookie('gp_pv', JSON.stringify(cookies), { expires: 50000, path: '/' }); 

        this.container.lookup('view:toplevel').rerender();
        route.transitionTo("index")
      }      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
      {{#if fieldUsed}}
        <style>
          #itemUsable {display:none;}
          #itemUsed {display:block;}
        </style>
      {{else}}
        <style>
          #itemUsable {display:block;}
          #itemUsed {display:none;}
        </style>      
      {{/if}}
      <div class="container" id="itemUsed">
        <div class="goodie-page-swipe-action">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
              <div class="btn gp-btn-primary btn-block btn-lg disabled">{{ t 'goodie.used'}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container" id="itemUsable">
        <div class="goodie-page-swipe-action">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
              <div {{ action 'markSwiped' }} class="btn gp-btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">{{ t 'goodie.use'}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Since it works fine(?) after a full refresh, it would seem your provided 'cookie setter' code works fine. Perhaps you (and us at SO) should be looking at the code responsible for displaying your button's state in reaction to the cookie data instead (or in addition).

Comment: Yes.. The cookie is set correctly. But the view is not refreshing and reloading that data.

Comment: Right, which means you would need to show more of your code in your question for someone to further help you.

Comment: Sorry.. It's there now .. :)

Comment: Add the `fieldUsed` computed property as well since that determines your button's visibility state, and any other potentially relevant code (of yours) that `fieldUsed` depends on.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had done that.. There you go.

Comment: To be clear.. The button switches state to "itemUsed" in the view.. But when I go back and forward again the state is "itemUsable" again.. Even though the cookie is set to be used. Only if i actually manually refresh the site it will show correct state as "itemUsed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed property values are normally cached and only updated when the values of the dependent keys change. From the provided code it is not immediately obvious that, when `markSwiped` gets run, `goodie.packContents.firstObject.id` immediately changes. I guess it doesn't, since `fieldUsed` and thus your templates do not get updated (which means the cookie value that you do update is never re-evaluated, until a full page refresh).

Things that come to mind that you could try:

- You could try to make `fieldUsed` a [volatile property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_volatile) which would hopefully cause it to be re-evaluated on every use (no longer cached)

  ```
  fieldUsed: function() {...}.volatile()
  ```
- Make `fieldUsed` depend on some other value instead, or in addition. For instance, as a crutch you could test some extraneous counter type variable that simply gets incremented somewhere in `markSwiped`

  ```
  crutchCounter: 0,
  fieldUsed: function() {}.property('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id', 'crutchCounter'),
  markSwiped: function() {...; this.incrementProperty('crutchCounter'); ...}
  ```

If either of these work, you can then also forego the jQuery DOM manipulation you have going on in `markSwiped`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
So should i remove the .property('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id') from fieldUsed and set .volatile() instead ?

Comment: It seems to be working to set .property('goodie.packContents.firstObject.id').volatile(),

Thank you so much